# How do I know if transaction code succeeded?

Tags: transactions, jdbi

The examples of @Transaction I see in the official [docs](http://jdbi.org/#_transaction_management) returns void and doesn't have a `throws` Exception declaration. Is there a runtime exception that happens if the transaction fails?

Comment: That should be esay to try. Just execute broken SQL inside the transaction and watch.

Comment: Per see that's what try/catch block are for; if it fail you can revert transaction. I doubt jdbi is different in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RollbackException is a RuntimeException. No throws necessary for that.